# Remove everything after second caret regex and apply to pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a dataframe with a column that looks like this:

```
0         EIAB^EIAB^6
1           8W^W844^A
2           8W^W844^A
3           8W^W858^A
4           8W^W844^A
             ...     
826136    EIAB^EIAB^6
826137    SICU^6124^A
826138    SICU^6124^A
826139    SICU^6128^A
826140    SICU^6128^A
```

I just want to keep everything before the second caret, e.g.: `8W^W844`, what regex would I use in Python? Similarly `PACU^SPAC^06` would be `PACU^SPAC`. And to apply it to the whole column.

I tried `r'[\\^].+$'` since I thought it would take the last caret and everything after, but it didn't work.

Comment: Are there ever more (or less) than two carets? Or is this a constant pattern?

Comment: It's a constant pattern.

Comment: For string `s` it can be retrieved with `s.rsplit("^", 1)[0]`.

Comment: It would be good to mention pandas in the question. There are fewer simple and workable solutions there. Sticking with regex is the best choice.

Comment: Gotcha, will add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can negate the character group to find everything except `^` and put it in a match group. you don't need to escape the `^` in the character group but you do need to escape the one outside.

```
re.match(r"([^^]+\^[^^]+)", "8W^W844^A").group(1)
```

This is quite useful in a pandas dataframe. Assuming you want to do this on a single column you can extract the string you want with

```
df['col'].str.extract(r'^([^^]+\^[^^]+)', expand=False)
```

**NOTE**

Originally, I used `replace`, but the `extract` solution suggested in the comments executed in 1/4 the time.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

df = pd.DataFrame({"foo":np.arange(1_000_000)})
df["bar"] = "8W^W844^A"
df2 = df.copy()

def t1():
    df.bar.str.replace(r"([^^]+\^[^^]+).*", r"\1", regex=True)
    
def t2():
    df.bar.str.extract(r'^([^^]+\^[^^]+)', expand=False)

print("replace", timeit("t1()", globals=globals(), number=20))
print("extract", timeit("t2()", globals=globals(), number=20))
```

output

```
replace 39.73989862400049
extract 9.910304663004354
```

Comment: Ding ding ding. We have a winner. `df['col'].str.replace(r"([^^]+\^[^^]+).*", r"\1", regex=True)`

Comment: I would expect `df['new'] = df['col'].str.extract(r'^([^^]+\^[^^]+)', expand=False)` to be more efficient than `replace`

Comment: Interesting. Will test it out.

Comment: I tested and @mozway's suggestion is 4 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think regex is really necessary here, just slice the string up to the position of the second caret:

```
>>> s = 'PACU^SPAC^06'
>>> s[:s.find("^", s.find("^") + 1)]
'PACU^SPAC'
```

*Explanation*: [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) accepts a second argument of where to start the search, place it just after the position of the first caret.

Comment: Awesome, that works! Thank you. Do you know how I could apply this to every element of one column in a pandas dataframe?